# Array slice not printing but var_dump does

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am trying to run code but, its not working.

```
$customerArray[] = [
    'name' => 'Delta Inc',
    'phone'=> '0123456789',
    'spend'=>1,
    'email' => 'info@acme.co.uk',
    'business_type_id'=>1
];
usort($customerArray, function($a, $b) {
    if($a['spend'] == $b['spend']) {
        return 0;
    } else if ($a['spend'] > $b['spend']) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
});
/* The top 10 elements are now on top of the array */    
$top = array_slice($customerArray, 0, 10);

/* If we reverse the array using array_reverse() the 
   smallest items are on top */
$low = array_slice(array_reverse($customerArray), 0, 10);
```

Upon `var_dump` its showing data when I do `var_dump('$top')`. But I want results of the query provided.

Comment: [array_slice()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) doesn't output anything, it simply returns an array value

Comment: @MarkBaker ok, thats useful but how do i get my output of my code.?

Comment: Iterate over the array, echoing the values, or var_dump($top), or whatever you want to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($top);
echo "</pre>";
```

This 
will loop through the array

```
foreach ($top AS $value){ 
    echo $value.'<br>' 
}
```

Or if you want to get a single item

```
echo $top[0];//Gets First item
echo $top[1];//Gets Second item
```

Comment: Basically i want to display topmost 10 number , and top 10 leaster number in a array. your code do the job, thank you but do you think my code is fine? It is fair to use array_slice in this situation.

Comment: There may be better ways to get the information, for instance where does the array come from. If it comes from a database you could fix the query to return what you want in advance. If the code works for you its fine.

Comment: my first approach was simple code to use max and min but min() didn't work, the code is just in one file. Do you think the code commented in the file is correct as i wanted to make it easy? My code is [here](http://pastebin.com/g7uc4Hh4)